# Can a hydraulic vane motor have a specific rotational output?

Tags: motors, pumps, hydraulics, stepper-motor

If a vane motor/pump was used in a hydraulic circuit, could the rotation of the vane pump be controlled for slight movement in angles?

I imagine this would would require a feedback controller, with position sensors. This controller would adjust the amount of flow and direction of flow of the hydraulic fluid.

The rotational output of the vane motor could be useful in similar circumstances where stepper motors are useful. Where specific and small amounts of rotation are required, with a holding torque

To summarize my question, can the rotational output of a vane motor be controller to specific angles and degrees? Or is a vane motor free rotating, and not easily specifically controlled from the flow of the hydraulic fluid?

Comment: Can you use a vane machine for hydraulics? I thought it only worked for gases because the volume decreases on compression but hydraulic fluids don't compress. I would expect the pump to burst.

Comment: There are better ways of controlling movement than relying on vane pump output. Lots of examples exist check out companies like Mannesman.

Comment: @Transistor vane pumps are used for fluids too. They’re a positive displacement pump

Comment: @SolarMike their website doesn’t have a product listing. I’m considering this vane pump idea for a small home project, to be 3d printed. So i am curious if the vane pump is the right direction to go, if it’s positioning control can be accurate